# Firefox css transition breaking on JQuery attribute change

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-transitions

When trying to change css attributes with jquery, Firefox won't show the resulting css transitions. It works fine on Chrome though.

SCSS

```
.wrap {
  width: 320px; border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  height: 480px; overflow: auto; 
  position: relative;
}
.top-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 320px; height: 60px;
  .menu-icon {
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;
    padding: 18px 20px;
  }
  .fix-search & {
    background: #eee;
  }
}

.search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 155px; left: 20px; right: 20px;
  input {
    width: 265px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: width 0.2s;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
  .fix-search & {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    input {
      width: 250px;
    }
  }
}
```

JS

```
var wrap = $("#wrap");

wrap.on("scroll", function(e) {

  if (this.scrollTop > 147) {
    wrap.addClass("fix-search");
  } else {
    wrap.removeClass("fix-search");
  }

});
```

The CodePen link replicates the problem. Any ideas how to make transitions work in Firefox?

See [CodePen](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/AdaKr) here.

Comment: Does adding `-moz-` prefix to `transition` help..? Which version of FF are you using..?

Comment: I tried prefixing it with -moz- but didn't fix the problem. FF 32.0.3 on linux.

Comment: css transitions are working fine on FF if attributes aren't changed with jquery, like, on triggering css change during hover, transitions work fine on FF